# close a sente session and redirect into login page in clojure/clojurescript

Tags: session, clojure, clojurescript

I have gone through the Sente Examples and created a login application with session.Now my session works fine.How can i close that particular session and redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server I added a logout ring route:

```
(POST "/logout" ring-req (logout-handler ring-req))
```

, which looks like this:

```
(defn logout-handler
  [ring-req]
  {:status 200 :session (assoc (:session ring-req) :uid nil)})
```

So just taking the `:uid` out of the session.

As far as being redirected to the login page, I have made it so that the client is always at the login page if the `:uid` is `nil`.

I am using Om Next with React 'controlled components' where the app state that comes into the root component determines what the user sees. Thus being 'redirected to the login page' is determined by the root render function:

```
(if (not (:app/authenticated? login-info))
  (show-login page ...)
  (show-start-of-app ...))
```

I haven't exactly tested this part of the app too well, but hopefully there's some ideas...